# Route separate, external static IPs to separate internal networks

Tags: networking, router

I'm looking after a network for a company that often rents office space to other businesses, sometimes at short notice. It would be useful to be able to offer a secure, separate network to these clients with little or no lead time.

What I'd like to do is have a router that could take a block of external static IPs (lets say 4) on a single ADSL connection and make each available on one of it's LAN ports. Obviously, none of the clients on one LAN should have access to any of the other LANs.

Ideally, the router would be able to provide DHCP for each LAN, or simply operate as a bridge so that another router could be used, if necessary, for the new company.

This seems like a simple enough request but none of the SOHO routers with which I'm familiar can apparently be configured in this way (even my Draytek which can support separate VLANs on each of it's physical LAN ports).

What sort of equipment do I need for this? Is there a better and / or definitive way of creating such a setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mulitple external IP addresses routed to various other networks is out of the realm of *most* SOHO routers.  You'll need to move up to something a little more robust.

There are plenty of routers out there to choose from.  Lots of people seem to use Ciscos (like the [1800-series](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps5853/index.html)) to do this stuff.  I personally like D-Link's [NetDefend firewalls](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps5853/index.html).

Also, if your router supports it, you may be able to get away with flashing it with [DD-WRT's firmware](http://www.dd-wrt.com), although I'm not sure if it will give you the features you need..

Comment: Thanks... I might actually have a Cisco 1841 I can play with, although it doesn't appear to have many Ethernet sockets (more can be added with expansion cards, yes?).